# C# - Getter and Setter dosen't keep the value

Tags: c#, getter-setter

Here is my code:

```
private int pressedMain = 1;

public int PressedMain
{
    get
    {
        return pressedMain;
    }

    set
    {
        pressedMain = value;
    }
}
```

And then I change the value of pressedMain:

```
pw.PressedMain++;
```

But in the following class my value is one, why and how can I slove this problem?

Comment: The code is correct, you should have an error anywhere else.

Comment: @Gusman I searched with debug but I did nothing found.

Comment: While running in the debugger, put a watch on `pw.PressedMain` and inspect the value both before and after calling `pw.PressedMain++;`.  This might add some insite to your situation.

Comment: add a breakpoint just in pw.PressedMain++; before executing it look at the value, and then again after it, you will see how it's incremented, and if the debugger returned it then the value has been stored by the property. Again, you have another error on your code, post more info.

Comment: @Gusman I changed 'private int pressedMain = 1;' to 'private static int pressedMain = 1'. It works now but I don't know if that's right :/

Comment: No, don't make it static, that makes it shared for all instances.

Comment: Then as I said, you have an error in your code and it's obvious, you're creating a new instance of the class which has that property each time instead of reusing the same instance.

Comment: Yep, agree with Gus. Post all your code so we can confirm but that sounds like the problem.

Comment: You are probably referring to another instance, that's why you still see it is 1.

Comment: @Gusman or he is checking his value in some way inside the class, not the instance.

Comment: @Wavum: Remember that a non-static class is just like a blueprint. If you want to get your value back, you need to get it out of the instance it was incremented on.

Comment: @C4ud3x no, he can't because it wasn't static before, then he can only see it on an instance.

Comment: Provide a full example with real results so we don't have to guess. What you have should work fine, but you haven't provided the full thing so we can't be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example invoke, console prints 2 here

```
  public class Foo
    {
        private int pressedMain = 1;
        public int PressedMain
        {
            get
            {
                return pressedMain;
            }

            set
            {
                pressedMain = value;
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.PressedMain++;

            Console.WriteLine(foo.PressedMain);

            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```